# .toggle() example doesn't work with jQuery 1.9

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Please see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1334/). It has a button that displays on hover.

Now try changing to jQuery 1.9.0, and notice that the Fiddle breaks.

Am I wrongly using `toggle()`? Is this my fault, or a bug with jQuery?

Comment: toggle was deprecated on jQuery ver 1.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `hover` pseudo event no longer exists, use mouseenter and mouseleave instead.

```
$('#user-rows').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.user-row', function () {
  $(this).find('.edit').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1337/

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event

Comment: Thats good to know! Though I do use the mouseenter and mouseleave I never knew that hover was eliminated :0